# Include Bower or NPM Component in Angular 2/4 cli Project

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, bower

I'm starting a simple Angular 4 project using the cli, and want to include a package from either NPM or Bower - the package in question is Multi Step Form (https://github.com/troch/angular-multi-step-form). I know I have to add it to the @NgModule class (previously angular.module, right?) but no matter what I try, Angular is either unable to see the module (with Bower), or gives an error message `Can't resolve 'angular' in [path-to-multi-step-form/dist/commonjs]`

Here is the app.module.ts file:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and here's the app.component.ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

Can anyone tell me where / how to include components into Angular 2/4 cli projects? I'm tearing my hair out and feeling pretty dumb since I've been working with Angular for a while now... :/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look at the documentation of the Module you are trying to add.

> **It says requirement 1.3 +**
>   [**LINK**](https://github.com/troch/angular-multi-step-form#requirements)

You are trying to add a AngularJS Module to Angular.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply Rahul! OK, so I assumed that since it works with AngularJS it would work with Angular 2/4. But what you say makes sense since the Angulars are so different.

Comment: @RunnyYolk yes both are different Angular and Angular JS . and the modules each have different implementation.